# Why is my Android Emulator crashing?

Tags: android, android-emulator, porting, android-2.2-froyo

I'm developing a application that works on linux. I want to port this to the Android SDK Emulator. But everytime I start the application the emulator crashed with a segmentation fault.

Somebody has any clue why a selfmade program that's running on the Android Emulator could crash the entire emulator?

Comment: What is the emulator stack trace. Does it happen with every AVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was a bug in the version of the emulator that I used. When I updated the emulator to the latest version, it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post up some code examples / logs of what is happening? You don't provide enough information for us to suggest why it would fail.

Best thing I can advise is to create a new emulator (only takes a few clicks) and try deploying your app on that, possibly try a different version.

If you can post up some logs/code examples of what might cause this, we can provide better answers

Answer (score 0):

Another debugging point to try would be launching a demo application/Hello Android on the emulator, to see if it is your application specifically.